# Add a new line after a specific word on text file using shell script

Tags: shell

Add the below line after the word "server {" in nginx.conf file.

```
location /nginx-status {
 stub_status on;
 allow all;
 }
```

Using the script below adds a new line next to the word "server {" wherever that word occurs.

```
echo Nginx conf_file_directory
location=$(which nginx)
export location

echo "Nginx configuration file directory"
path=$($location -V 2>&1|grep -Po '(?<=--conf-path=).*?(?=/[^/]+(\s|$))')
export path
echo $path

dir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
echo $dir
export dir

echo "create nginx configuration content file"
cat << 'EOF' > $dir/content.txt
    location /nginx-status {
    stub_status on;
    allow all;
    }

EOF

echo "CONF_FILE file start"
sed -i  '/server {/r content.txt'  $path/nginx.conf

echo "Delete the nginx configuration content file"
file="$dir/content.txt"

if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    rm "$file"
   echo "deleted"
fi
```

The nginx.conf file contains more than one word "server {". But I need to find the word first and add the below lines to the next line. Only the first word "server {" is uncommented, all other "server {" words are commented in nginx.conf file

```
location /nginx-status {
 stub_status on;
 allow all;
 }
```

Comment: Add a complete [mcve].  What is the original file, what it should look like after the addition?  Then show what your code produces.  And debug steps.

Comment: @Nic3500 I already mention sir "Using the script below adds a new line next to the word "server {" wherever that word occurs."

Comment: Please, anybody answer this question

Comment: So provide a sample original file so we can test our answers before posting.  I am not an nginx expert, but adding lines in config files, that I can do.